# Push feature branch that was created from master to develop

Tags: git, bitbucket, devops, branching-and-merging

We are in the starting stage of setting up dev-ops in our organization.  We have 2 branches called 'master' and 'develop' and both the branches are empty with folder structure.  Our developers created 'feature' branch from 'master' branch and developed their components.  The components are available in the 'feature' branch.

Ideally the developer should create from 'develop' but due to some misunderstanding they have created from 'master'.

Is there a way to push the 'feature' branch that was created from 'master' to 'develop' branch.

Comment: If a branch was created off of the wrong commit, why not rebase it onto the right commit? Isn't that exactly what rebase is for?

Answer (score -1):

In our organization we follow kinda similar structure and we have our `main` and `develop` branch along with `feature`, `release` and `hotfix` branches. You mentioned that `feature` branches should be created from `develop` branch and I agree with you.

In my opinion I would suggest you not to worry about the already created branches from the `main` but look forward to create future `feature` branches from `develop` branch. I suggest you, once the work is done with `feature` branches which are directly created from `main`, raise merge requests to `develop`. Once those branches are tested in `develop` then merge with `main`.